# Copying directory doesn't copy source folder Java

Tags: java, copy, directory

I am trying to copy a folder/file from one location to another in Java. I am a beginner in Java and I fould a neat little library, I believe it is called Apache FileUtils, which has a FileUtils.CopyDirectory() method which should copy a folder from one destination to another. However, for me it only copies what is inside the folder itself.

```
else if (command.equals("COPY")){
        System.out.println("Enter the path of the file/folder you wish to copy : ");
        Scanner scannerPath = new Scanner(System.in);
        path = scannerPath.nextLine();
        File copiedFolder = new File(path);
        System.out.println("Enter the path where you want to copy the file/folder: ");
        String newpath = scannerPath.nextLine();
        File copyFolder = new File(newpath);
        if (copiedFolder.isDirectory() && copiedFolder.exists())
        {

            FileUtils.copyDirectory(copiedFolder, copyFolder);
            System.out.println("Copy successful !");
        }
        else if (copiedFolder.isFile())
        {

            FileUtils.copyFile(copiedFolder, copyFolder);
            System.out.println("Copy successful !");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Copy failed. Check if the file/folder exists !");
        }
```

It should copy the whole directory, but for some reason It does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [copyDirectory](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)) :

> The destination is the new location and name of the directory.

and

> If the destination directory did exist, then this method merges the
>   source with the destination, with the source taking precedence.

So basically the target directory will represent itself the copy of your source directory.

You may consider adding a subdirectory with the desired name in the path, like :

```
File copyFolder = new File(newpath + File.separator + copiedFolder.getName());
```